# rotation angles

Tags: python, pose-mode

I'm trying to convert an animation format from a game to blender pose animation and back.
The first step is OK, but when I try to export it, I find the joints from the original animation can rotate from -360 to 359.9 degrees. So blender pose bone does not provide enough informations to reverse the conversion.
Can somebody give me some ideas?

Edit

I figured out the cause of my problem was the Euler angels I got were on the wrong axis, for example I needed 182 degree but it gave -178 degree, so the character rotated in the wrong direction.

Now the question becomes how do I properly convert Quaternions to Euler angles. I overlooked the compactible Euler parameter of Quaternion.toEuler before, maybe it is the answer.

Comment: It would probably help potential answerers to have a blend file to look at. :P

Comment: Sorry, I read some python API documents yesterday, perhaps the compact Euler parameter of Quaternion.toEuler is the  answer. Need to do some test first.